# Number of Integer Solutions modified

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I wanted to verify my solution to the following problem.

**Say I have a linear equation of $50$ terms $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{50}$ that must sum to $1$, where each $x_i\in[-1,1]$ in increments of $0.01$. I want to determine the total number of solutions that exist to this problem.**

Since the interval is closed, I treat this as an integer problem where each $0.01$ can be thought of as $1$ over the interval of $[-100,100]$. As such, the solution should be of the form
$$\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$$

where $n$ is modified to accompany the negative range of values, so we take $y_i=x_i+100$ for each term and add this to our modified sum of $1$. Our new expression should be: 
$$y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_{50}=100+50\cdot100=5100$$
All possible solutions should be the following
$$\binom{5000+50-1}{50-1}=\binom{5049}{49}\approx3.728×10^{118}$$

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $5100$ in the last line, not $5000$; what you calculated is the number of solutions to $\sum_i x_i=0$. The number of solutions to $\sum_i x_i=1$ is

$$
\binom{5100+50-1}{50-1}=\binom{5149}{49}\approx9.791×10^{118}\;.
$$